# Displacement Modifier Stretching

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I am trying to model a heightmap using a plane, but for some reason the texture I use keeps distorting? What am I doing wrong here? (I am using the smiley as an example to show the stretching)
[image: Exa]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with changing the texture mapping to UV